# Jenkins pipeline terraform plan failing

Tags: azure, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, terraform-provider-azure

```
pipeline{
       agent any
stages{
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
            git branch: 'master',
                credentialsId: 'xxx-test-credentials',
                url: 'https://gitlab.com/xxxx-xxxx/xxxxx/terraform.git'

            sh "pwd"
            sh "ls -lat"
        }
    }

    stage('Set Terraform path') {
    steps {
      script {
        def tfHome = tool name: 'Terraform'
        env.PATH = "${tfHome}:${env.PATH}"
       }
       sh 'terraform version'

      }
    }

    stage('Provision infrastructure') {
        steps {
          dir('environments/dev')
          {
              withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal('xxx-test-service-principal')]) {
                  script{
                    sh  'terraform init'
                    sh  'terraform plan'
                    sh  'az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET -t $AZURE_TENANT_ID'

                    }
              }
                // sh ‘terraform destroy -auto-approve’
          }

        }
    }
  }
}
```

I ran the above basic pipeline which runs Terraform init and plan. I have used the service principal credentials created to authenticate with the subscription where I wanted to create the resources but I get the below error even though Azure CLI plugin has been installed on the Jenkins from where I'm trying to run this pipeline.

[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError refreshing state: 1 error occurred:
    * provider.azurerm: Error building AzureRM Client: Azure CLI Authorization Profile was not found. Please ensure the Azure CLI is installed and then log-in with `az login`.

[0m

[0m[0m[0m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you need to auth first and do plan after, try this:

```
sh  'az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET -t $AZURE_TENANT_ID'
sh  'terraform init'
sh  'terraform plan'
```

Comment: well this time it's `az: command not found` even though I have already installed the Azure cli plugin. May be the order of running the commands would work if the `az login` worked fine...

Comment: no, it wouldn't because terraform would try and take auth details from az, if you didn't login with az - there is nothing to take. so you need to install `az cli` first

Comment: yes I would need to install az cli as part of jenkins docker image as the `Azure cli` plugin for Jenkins is not integratable with the Jenkins pipeline...